# Can WP-CLI modify database connection details in existing wp-config file?

Tags: wp-config, wp-cli

I am aware of WP-CLI's many database interaction functions via "[wp db](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/)" and its functions for *generating* wp-config files via "[wp config](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/config/)" - However I cannot find a way of using WP-CLI to modify existing database name, username and password settings in wp-config.

I am migrating multiple sites, and the ability to do this would be a time saver.

I am aware that wp config can launch vi editor (`wp config edit`), but I am looking for a way to pass the database name, username and password TO WP-CLI to have it do the job for me. Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp config set` to update any existing value in wp-config or to add a new value:

```
wp config set DB_NAME some_db_name
wp config set DB_USER some_db_username
wp config set DB_PASSWORD you_secret_value_pass
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/config/set/

Keep in mind that values are case sensitive, so if you do `wp config set db_name some-db`, it will add a NEW value rather than update the value for `DB_NAME`.